# -bash: cd: Desktop: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, directory, cd-command

I'm trying to type:

```
cd Desktop
```

from the `/root` directory, but when I do it comes up with the error:

```
-bash: cd: Desktop: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you running this command from? What is the output of `pwd`? And what is the output of `ls -ld Desktop`?

Comment: I'm running it from /root

Comment: Normally _root_ user's home directory is `/root`, but it will not contain a `Desktop` directory because _root_ user is not and **should not** be used to login into desktop.

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: @Malicious depends. What do you actually want to do? Why do you want to `cd` into `/root/Desktop`?

Comment: I'm trying to get the files I installed to end up in my Desktop.

Comment: @Malicious you don't want to install things on your Desktop, they wouldn't work. It's probably best if you ask a new question, starting from the beginning. Explain what you have done (what and how did you install), and what you are trying to do. If you just want an icon on your Desktop that  you can click on to launch something, that can be done, but we need to know the while situation.

Comment: I'm trying to get this thing from git called cupp into my desktop so I can access the wordlists.

Answer (score 4):

The `/root` directory is the home directory of the `root` user. This user doesn't have a `Desktop` by default since root isn't supposed to log in graphically, so you are getting that error simply because you are trying to `cd` into a directory that doesn't exist.

If you want to `cd` into *your* desktop, try:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

Although, if you are in `/root`, you are probably logged in as root, so that won't work either.

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: @Malicious yes, of course it doesn't work. As I explained in the answer, there is no `/root/Desktop` directory. And, as  I also mentioned, if you are in `/root`, then you are probably logged in as the root user so `~/Desktop` will also not work because that will be expanded to `/root/Desktop`. You cannot `cd` into a directory that doesn't exist.

Comment: I tried the commands and it said when I typed cd /root/Desktop/ it said -bash: cd: /root/Desktop/: Permission denied what do I do?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running it from **/root** then you are running it with **root** privilages. That means you are not an ordinary *user* and your default directory **~** will be **/root**. You are probably logged in as root. So you should *log in with another user* or you can just go (supposing your default is **/root** and from **/root**) `cd /home/{your_username}/Desktop/`.

Answer (score 1):

try this (user account):

```
cd $(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)
```