# -bash: cd: Desktop: No such file or directory despite not being in /root

Tags: command-line, bash

I am following a tutorial on the use of Docker/rocker containers that requires me to create a repository on my desktop. Working within ubuntu, my command line ends in "$", indicating that I am not in /root and should therefore be able to access the desktop; however, when I run `cd Desktop` I receive the error message `-bash: cd: Desktop: No such file or directory`. According to information gleaned from  [this q&a on ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146123/bash-cd-desktop-no-such-file-or-directory), I should only get this error if I am in /root (cmd line ending in "#"), which is not the case. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 3):

At its most fundamental, the problem is that there is no directory named `Desktop` in the location from which you are trying to execute the `cd` command. You can check where that is using the `pwd` command, and you can see what files and/or directories it contains using `ls`.

You may be confusing two different meanings of the term "in root"

- in (i.e. logged in to) the `root` user account
- in (i.e. with your shell's current working directory set to) `/root`

Conventionally, the bash shell indicates the first of these with a `#` prompt (although there's nothing to stop anyone from changing that - it's just a matter of setting the `PS1` shell variable). It's really the second that determines whether `cd Desktop` will "work"; since `/root` is the default home directory of the `root` user account, you are initially "in /root" when you log in as `root`, but that is only one of an almost unlimited number of locations that **don't** contain a `Desktop` directory.

Comment: Thank you so much! Having realized that I couldn't possibly access Desktop from that location, I tried your suggestions but still couldn't get to Desktop after going to the top of the tree I was in. After some googling, I found that the that command <cd "C:\Users\myusername\OneDrive\Desktop"> worked from the Command Prompt window, and <cd C:\Users\myusername\OneDrive\Desktop> (no quotation marks) worked from the PowerShell. However, after having entered ubuntu in PowerShell (meaning after running <wsl>), I still could not get to the Desktop with either of these commands. Any ideas?

Comment: "I tried your suggestions" means I navigated to the top of the tree by running <cd ..> a few times, my reasoning being that I should be able to access the Desktop from a higher/highest position.

Comment: @MarkFeatherstone so you are trying to access a **Windows** desktop folder from **WSL**? That information would have been useful to include in your question.

Comment: @MarkFeatherstone ... see for example [How to get to the Windows Desktop in WSL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389080/how-to-get-to-the-windows-desktop-in-wsl)

Comment: My apologies. I am relatively new to this (meaning anything beyond GUI), and I assumed, incorrectly, that if I was using ubuntu and desktop in the same breath, then that must convey going to a Windows desktop folder from WSL. I will check out that link.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, my question concerned accessing a Windows 11 desktop folder from WSL (Ubuntu). The reason I was unable to access my Windows desktop using the most popular command is explained as follows. It seems that as part of my Windows 11 installation, I chose the default setting in response to "Back up your files with OneDrive" which set OneDrive as the default save location for Desktop, Documents, and Pictures folders/files. As a result, from wsl in PowerShell, the most often suggested command for accessing the Desktop `/mnt/c/Users/username$ cd Desktop` does not work. Instead, the correct command is `/mnt/c/Users/username$ cd OneDrive/Desktop` where `/mnt/c/Users/username$` is the prompt and `cd OneDrive/Desktop` is the actual command. This correctly sets the path to Desktop through OneDrive. Of course "username" must be replaced with one's own PC username. [This site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/files-save-to-onedrive-by-default-in-windows-10-33da0077-770c-4bda-b61e-8c8e8ca70ac7#) was useful in clarifying the matter.

If instead one is working directly within the Ubuntu terminal (accessed from the dropdown menu in PowerShell), run `cd mnt/c/Users/msfea/OneDrive/Desktop` at the command line to actually go to the Desktop. To merely see what is on the Desktop, run `ls mnt/c/Users/msfea/OneDrive/Desktop`. See [this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531576/how-do-i-access-my-windows-desktop-directory-from-inside-windows-subsystem-for-l).